# Texto vertical con css

Tags: css, scss

Estoy trarando de colocar textos en forma vertical, pero tengo un problema que se puede ver en el codigo, los textos no salen uno al lado del otro, sino, debajo.

Dejo el codigo!
Gracias!

```css
a {text-decoration: none;}
.p-v {
display: block;
margin-left: -7px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06494d4185.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
<div>
<a href="#">
<span class="p-v">INSTAGRAM</span> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#">
<span class="p-v">FACEBOOK</span> <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entendi si lo que quieres es esto, pero quizá te sirva añadir `display: inline-block` al `DIV`, además rote los iconos ya que me pareció correcto, quedo asi:

```css
a {text-decoration: none;}
.p-v {
display: block;
margin-left: -7px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

div {
display: inline-block;
}

i {
margin-left: -7px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
transform:rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06494d4185.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
<div>
<a href="#">
<span class="p-v">INSTAGRAM</span> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#">
<span class="p-v">FACEBOOK</span> <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si, era eso. Use `display`, pero nunca se me ocurrio usar `inline-block`. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Con css y el atributo display en inline-block en el div  te puede funcionar el efecto que buscas

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
.p-v {
display: block;
margin-left: -7px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
div {
display: inline-block;
}
```

esto puede afectar a otros elementos div que agregues por lo que puedes asignarle una clase a los que desees